# Open page based on $(this) selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm modifying a wordpress site and have a menu with four anchor tags (buttons) to the left of a slider. When a user selects a button, the slide associated with the button shows. Now, I'd like to open a page when the user clicks the button, instead of showing the slide. Here is the code so far:

```
$('#slidernavigation > a').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $a = $(this);
    $(this).showSlide();    
    if($a.id == $('#slide-1285')){
        console.log('testing');
    }
    else{
        console.log('not-testing');
    }               

});
```

Here I'm testing to see if I can click on the anchor with the id '#slide-1285' and log it to the console. It always says 'not testing'. I'm going to set up conditions for all id's so a user is redirected to the correct page. Something like this:

```
$('#slidernavigation > a').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();


    $(this).showSlide();

    if($a.id == $('#slide-1285')){
        window.location.href = "http://webpage1";
    }

    elseif($a.id == $('#slide-1286')){
        window.location.href = "http://webpage2";
    }           

    elseif($a.id == $('#slide-1287')){
        window.location.href = "http://webpage3";
    }   

    else($a.id == $('#slide-1288')){
        window.location.href = "http://webpage4";
    }           


});
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "open a page when the user clicks [link]" — is the default link behavior. If you put the url in `href` and remove the script at all it will open a page :)

Comment: `$a.id` doesn't exist, and `$('#slide-1288')` isn't an ID.

Comment: instead of writing $.id ,you should write $a.attr('id') and this should be checked like this :- if( $a.attr('id') == slide-1285)... not the way you are doing :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the id of the element that was clicked, you can do:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

That will return a string. So you could do:

```
if($(this).attr('id') === 'slide-1285') { do something }
```

`$('#slide-1285')` would return a jquery element, but you want just the id. I think the code above is more what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new `data` attribute to each of your link and then get that value and redirect.

```
<a data-webpage="http://webpage1" href="whatever" id="slide-123"></a>
<a data-webpage="http://webpage2" href="whatever" id="slide-456"></a>
.....
```

and then

```
// this will bind all ids starting with slide-
    $('[id^=slide-]').on('click', function(e){
         // some code.
         window.location.href = $(this).data('webpage');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) you are comparing `$a.id`, that is string, to object `$('#slide-1285');`.

2) To simplify:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
       window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

```html
<a href='http://google.com' class='a'>Google!</a><br/>
<a href='http://stackoverflow.com' class='a'>SO!</a><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery objects have no `id` property. You need to do `attr('id')`, or just get the `id` property of the plain DOM object. Additionally, jQuery objects are never going to equal each other. Third, you want to check if the clicked element has a certain ID, which can be done using `.is()`.

In sum, you could do one of these:

Comparing strings:

```
$('#slidernavigation > a').on('click', function(e){

   if(this.id == '#slide-1285'){
        console.log('testing');
    }

    else{
        console.log('not-testing');
    }               

});
```

Using `.is()`:

```
$('#slidernavigation > a').on('click', function(e){

   if($(this).is('#slide-1285')){
        console.log('testing');
    }

    else{
        console.log('not-testing');
    }               

});
```

Or, just let the browser do its thing. Give your `<a>`s `href` attributes, and they'll function as links, even without JS.

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing  $.id

you should write

```
 $a.attr('id')
```

and this should be checked like this :-

```
 if( $a.attr('id') == slide-1285)
```

not the way you are doing :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var pages = [{"slide-1285" : "http://webpage1"}
             , {"slide-1286" : "http://webpage2"}
             , {"slide-1287" : "http://webpage3"}
             , {"slide-1288" : "http://webpage4"}
            ];

$('#slidernavigation > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nav = e.target.id;
    $.grep(pages, function(page) {
        if (nav in page) {
            window.location.href = page[nav];
        }
    })
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/2nf97dfr/

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="a">
    dhjdfd
</div>



   $('#a').on('click',function(e){ 
       var clickedElement= e.srcElement; 
        if($(clickedElement).attr("id") == "abc"){
         //do something   
        } 
    });
```

just use e.srcElement to get the element reference and then get its id.. and btw u can use switch case rather than multiple if else statements ..

working fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/alokbhat/4jup2ydw/)